# Who discovered that logarithmic integral is asymptotic to prime counting function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, math-history

We know that Gauss discovered that $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log(n)}$. This is also known as prime number theorem.

Prime number theorem also says $\int_0^{n} \frac{dt}{\log(t)} \sim \pi(n)$. The question is who first discovered this?

Some sources say that Legendre discovered it. I couldn't find a source about this on wikipedia. I even asked ChatGPT and it said that Gauss discovered.

Comment: Wikipedia says:"*In 1838 Peter Gustav Lejeune Dirichlet came up with his own approximating function, the logarithmic integral li(x) (under the slightly different form of a series, which he communicated to Gauss)*. And of course $li(x)=\int_0^{x} \frac{dt}{\log(t)}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes but no reference

Comment: 1. Forget ChatGPT !! 2. Do you mean who discovered it or who proved it ? This need not be the same ?

Comment: Ingham says that Gauss knew this as early as 1791  when he was  fourteen years old, although his letter to Encke was 1849  and first published in 1863.  Both footnotes on that page for Gauss and Dirichlet are their collected works. For Gauss he says pages ii and 444-447. He says Hargreave and Chebyshev were 1849

Comment: @Peter I mean who discovered

Comment: some detail given at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/who-first-identified-fracn-lnn-as-an-approximation-of-a-prime-counting